# how to distribute several arrows vertically in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am currently working on a paper, where I need to create few TikZ graphics that contain rectangles with multiple arrows between them.

This is a simple example with only one arrow:

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{myblock} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height=3cm] 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo)[myblock]{foo};
    \node (bar)[myblock,right-of=foo,xshift=5cm]{bar};
    \draw[->] (foo) -- node[below] {arrow text} (bar);
    % more arrows here
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Between different (TikZ) pictures the number of arrows and height of the two blocks differ (in one picture both of them always have the same height). The text is always short enough to fit into a single line.

Given two rectangles and a certain amount of arrows (with different directions and text), how do I distribute them equally over the height of the two blocks? Is there any automation of TikZ I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite straight forward in the sense that you can use `calc` library of `tikz` and access the points between two points with any ratio. For example, `($(foo.north east)!0.25!(foo.south east)$)` is the point that is 25% away from `foo.north east` on the line connecting `foo.north east` and `foo.south east`. Hence we could use

```
\draw[->] ($(foo.north east)!0.25!(foo.south east)$) -- node[below] 
          {arrow text} ($(bar.north west)!0.25!(bar.south west)$);
```

Full code will be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{myblock/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum height=3cm}
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo)[myblock]{foo};
    \node (bar)[myblock,right of=foo,xshift=5cm]{bar};
    \draw[->] ($(foo.north east)!0.25!(foo.south east)$) -- node[below] {arrow text} ($(bar.north west)!0.25!(bar.south west)$);
    \draw[->] ($(foo.north east)!0.5!(foo.south east)$) -- node[below] {arrow text} ($(bar.north west)!0.5!(bar.south west)$);
    \draw[->] ($(foo.north east)!0.75!(foo.south east)$) -- node[below] {arrow text} ($(bar.north west)!0.75!(bar.south west)$);
    % more arrows here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding to this you can also use a `\foreach` loop to draw the lines and reduce the code lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{myblock/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum height=3cm}
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo)[myblock]{foo};
    \node (bar)[myblock,right of=foo,xshift=5cm]{bar};
    \foreach \a/\b in {0.25/arrow text,0.5/arrow,0.75/text}{
    \draw[->] ($(foo.north east)!\a!(foo.south east)$) -- node[below] {\b} ($(bar.north west)!\a!(bar.south west)$);
   }
    % more arrows here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! But how could I provide a custom text and direction for each arrow, if I used a `\foreach` loop?

Comment: @muffel For custom text, I have added an example. Can you elaborate on custom direction?

Comment: I just refer to the arrow direction, so e.g. in your example above the second arrow should be from right to left, instead of left to right

Comment: @muffel So the direction is randomly to left/right. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good in expressing what I really mean. The order is not random. For each arrow I want to specify the text as well as the direction, e.g. `\foreach \a/\b in {0.25/arrow text/left,0.5/arrow/left,0.75/text/right}{ }`, where *left* or *right* just refer to the direction where the tip of the arrow points to (so `\draw[<-]` or `\draw[->]`)

Comment: @muffel Use two `\foreach` loops: one for left to right and the other for right to left if you don't want more trouble.

Comment: really great solution!

Comment: So nice to see you, Harish!