# How do I add more arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=3em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

%Blocks
\draw (0,1.5) node(inputNode)[shape=rectangle,minimum
width = 5, minimum height = 3] {$(f_{id},X_h)$};
\draw (1.5,1.5) node(LUT)[draw,shape=rectangle,minimum
width = 50, minimum height = 100,fill=black!10,thick] {LUT};
\draw (3.0,1.5) node(outputNode)[shape=rectangle,minimum 
width = 5, minimum height = 3] {$y$};

%Arcs
\draw[>=latex,->,thick] (inputNode.east) -- (LUT.west);
\draw[>=latex,->,thick] (LUT.east) -- (outputNode.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Architecture block diagram.}
\label{fig:arch}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which compile and works. I was wondering how can I add more horizzontal arrow at the right of the box, but at different heights. Any clue?

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256016/how-to-distribute-several-arrows-vertically-in-tikz helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer linked to by Torbjørn T. is ok for a few set of lines. If you need more sets of parallel lines, here is a solution with a special decoration:

Options:

`amplitude` is used her as the distance between the outer most lines. This is an option used for many decorations. It's default is 2.5pt. So it should be set.

`parallels number` is the number of parallel lines. The default is 2.

`parallels arrow start` and `parallels arrow end` is used to define arrow heads for start and end. Default: no arrow heads.

The distance from line to line is `amplitude` / (`parallels number` - 1).

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=3em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/decoration/.cd,
    parallels number/.store in=\pgfparallelsnumber,
    parallels arrow start/.store in=\pgfparallelsarrowstart,
    parallels arrow end/.store in=\pgfparallelsarrowend,
    parallels number=2,
    parallels arrow start={},
    parallels arrow end={},
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{parallels}{parallels}
{
  \state{parallels}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}% take over outside line width
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{\pgfparallelsarrowstart}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{\pgfparallelsarrowend}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\plnum}{\pgfparallelsnumber-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\plampratiostep}{1/\plnum}
    \foreach \ply in {0,...,\plnum}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\plamplituderatio}{0.5-\ply*\plampratiostep}
      {
        \pgftransformyshift{\plamplituderatio\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}% needed here, to draw the arrow heads
      }
    }
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

%Blocks
\draw (0,1.5) node(inputNode)[shape=rectangle,minimum
width = 5, minimum height = 3] {$(f_{id},X_h)$};
\draw (1.5,1.5) node(LUT)[draw,shape=rectangle,minimum
width = 50, minimum height = 100,fill=black!10,thick] {LUT};
\draw (3.0,1.5) node(outputNode)[shape=rectangle,minimum 
width = 5, minimum height = 3] {$y$};

\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=8,amplitude=1.4cm,parallels arrow end=latex}] (inputNode.east) -- (LUT.west);
\draw[thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=3,amplitude=0.4cm,parallels arrow end=latex}] (LUT.east) -- (outputNode.west);

%testing
\begin{scope}[decoration={parallels,parallels number=3,amplitude=0.4cm,parallels arrow end=latex}]
\draw[thick,decorate] (1  ,-0.5) -- (0.5, 0);
\draw[thick,decorate] (1.5,-0.5) -- (1.5, 0);
\draw[thick,decorate] (2  ,-0.5) -- (2.5, 0);
\draw[thick,decorate] (2  ,-1  ) -- (2.5,-1);
\draw[thick,decorate] (2  ,-1.5) -- (2.5,-2);
\draw[thick,decorate] (1.5,-1.5) -- (1.5,-2);
\draw[thick,decorate] (1  ,-1.5) -- (0.5,-2);
\draw[thick,decorate] (1  ,-1  ) -- (0.5,-1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result (with a few arrows for testing below your picture):

[image]

**Edit:** labeling the lines

Remark: the previous version had no color support, which I added here. Since I couldn't figure out, how to get the outside color, I added an option `parallels color`, which must be used, if the lines should be in another color then black (the default).

Now for the labeling:

Labels can be set nearly the same way as for normal lines. But they have to be shifted by half the amplitude for proper positioning. One label for all lines can be achived with e.g.

```
\draw[decorate,decoration={parallels,amplitude=0.4cm,}]
    (0,1) -- node[above,yshift=0.2cm]{label above} (2,1);
```

If a label for each line is desired, first a larger amplitude must be set, so there is enough space between the lines for the text. Then multiple lables can be used. E.g.

```
\draw[decorate,decoration={parallels,amplitude=1cm,}]
    (0,1) -- node[above,yshift=0.5cm]{label above line 1}
             node[above,yshift=-0.5cm]{label above line 2} (2,1);
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfkeys{%
    /pgf/decoration/.cd,
    parallels number/.store in=\pgfparallelsnumber,
    parallels arrow start/.store in=\pgfparallelsarrowstart,
    parallels arrow end/.store in=\pgfparallelsarrowend,
    parallels color/.code={\colorlet{parallelscolor}{#1}},
    parallels number=2,
    parallels arrow start={},
    parallels arrow end={},
    parallels color={black}
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{parallels}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth} % take over outside line width
    \pgfsetcolor{parallelscolor}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{\pgfparallelsarrowstart}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{\pgfparallelsarrowend}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\plnum}{\pgfparallelsnumber-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\plampratiostep}{1/\plnum}
    \foreach \ply in {0,...,\plnum}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\plamplituderatio}{0.5-\ply*\plampratiostep}
      {
        \pgftransformyshift{\plamplituderatio\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}% needed here, to draw the arrow heads
      }
    }
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[blue,thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=8,amplitude=1.4cm,parallels arrow end=latex,parallels color=blue}]
    (0,1) -- node[above,yshift=0.7cm]{label above} (2,1);
\draw[green,thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=3,amplitude=0.4cm,parallels arrow end=latex,parallels color=green}]
    (0,0.5) -- node[below,yshift=-0.2cm]{label below} (2,0.5);
\draw[magenta,thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=3,amplitude=1.2cm,parallels arrow end=latex,,parallels color=magenta}]
    (0,-0.3) -- node[above,yshift=0.6cm]{label 1 above}
                node[above]{label 2 above}
                node[above,yshift=-0.6cm]{label 3 above} (2,-0.3);
\draw[cyan,thick,decorate,decoration={parallels,parallels number=4,amplitude=1.8cm,parallels arrow end=latex,,parallels color=cyan}]
    (0,-1.2) -- node[below,yshift=0.9cm]{label 1 below}
                node[below,yshift=0.3cm]{label 2 below}
                node[below,yshift=-0.3cm]{label 3 below}
                node[below,yshift=-0.9cm]{label 4 below} (2,-1.2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about If I wanted to label them?

Comment: @user8469759 I added an example for labeling.